# Stack Overflow doesn't render some pages in Chrome with my Google profile

Tags: bug, login, advertising, rendering

I have a Stack Overflow account linked to my Google profile. I have had difficulty loading many pages over the last month or perhaps longer.

For example, [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421246/how-to-build-and-push-a-docker-image-in-a-terraform-docker-provider-by-gcp-cloud).

Some pages render fine, but often no page content appears, or small parts of the elements appear and then disappear as I hover. Not always the same content. So it appears to be a rendering issue.
I can see HTML has loaded in the console.
I can see the CSS elements are loaded including iframes with google syndication content, but the page is mostly white.

There is no issue with Firefox or Chrome in incognito. 
The issue is on Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I use the SO Dark Theme. I logged into Firefox and changed SO user preference to the default theme.  I can see this change in the CSS class in the chrome console. Still some pages don't render.

I have used [AdBlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdBlock) with this setup for a long time. When running I see these errors in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j98&tid=UA-108242619-1&cid=691182666.1663208611&jid=267176607&uid=2304362&gjid=1109973790&_gid=924458756.1666743069&_u=SCCACEAAFAAAACAAI~&z=2029143401:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Pausing AdBlock on this site removes those errors, but does not fix the rendering issue.

Sometime I see this warning, which related to devices so is understandable and probably not relevant to a Windows desktop browser.

```
moatad.js:139 The deviceorientation events are blocked by permissions policy. See https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/master/features.md#sensor-features
```

My workaround is to paste the message into Firefox, where the page renders fine, even if logged in. But I am not usually logged in on that browser.

I know that SO doesn't want to inflict ads on people who don't want or use them.

Another workaround is to disable AdBlock completely. This affects all sites. So perhaps this is part of Google Chrome's new  "Manifest V3"  technology to thwart AdBlockers. But that is not supposed to be rolled out yet.

Has anyone else experienced these symptoms or found the root cause?

Comment: [AdBlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdBlock), not [Adblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) (ABP)?

Comment: I am starting to see similar issues in other non-SO sites. Indicating it is more to do with having a hundred tabs open or some other memory issue in the browser.